# How move leafle control layers to above map?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I have a leaflet map, I use [this](https://github.com/gokertanrisever/leaflet-ruler) `Leaflet-Ruler` plugin and add ruler control layer to map in [this link](https://jsfiddle.net/magi2109/dkbywmqe/6/). I want move ruler control layers to above map as shown as:

[image]

How Can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need move one DIV element inside another DIV with JQuery  `$("#source").appendTo("#destination");` for example I move DIV ruler control that class name was `leaflet-ruler` move to the my special DIV `<div id='move-control-layer-ruler-to-here'></div>` .

You can move any control layer leaflet to any DIV.

This [link is jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/magi2109/4ypc1wbv/7/) solved my problem.

[image]]